# How to write SQL for finding columns with matching string

Tags: mysql, sql

I do have a following table

TableA
| Column A | Column B |
| -------- | -------- |
| 1234     | Y        |
| 2345     | N        |
| 3456     | Y        |
| 3456     | Y        |
| 3456     | N        |
| 2345     | N        |
| 1234     | N        |
| 2345     | N        |

Here, '1234' and '3456' has values Y and N whereas 2345 has only value N

I want to display values of column A where there are 2 values (Y and N) in Column B. Ideally
| Column A | Column B |
| -------- | -------- |
| 1234     | Y        |
| 1234     | N        |
| 3456     | Y        |
| 3456     | N        |

I tried using

Select * from TableA
where column b = 'Y'
and column b = 'N'

but it doesn't give desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT ColumnA
FROM TableA
GROUP BY ColumnA
HAVING MIN(ColumnB) <> MAX(ColumnB);
```

The above assumes that the only two values which would ever appear in `ColumnB` are `Y` and `N`.